# Transparent background behind font

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

With LWJGL and OpenGL, I want to draw a textured rectangle. 
Above that, I want to write some Text using the Slick Library. 
My Problem is that when I draw the Text before the rectangle, the font has a transparent background. See it here:

[image]

If I draw the text after the rectangle, I cant see it. Now I've googled about an hour and found several possible solutions but none worked for me.

The Code :

FontVeranda.java

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bunchofpunch.fonts;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont;
import org.newdawn.slick.font.effects.ColorEffect;

/**
 *
 * @author Alex
 */
public class FontVeranda 
{
    private UnicodeFont font;
    private boolean shouldRenderFont = true;

    public void loadFont()
    {
        java.awt.Font awtFont = new java.awt.Font("Veranda", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 14);
        font = new UnicodeFont(awtFont);
        font.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.black));
        font.addAsciiGlyphs();
        try {
            font.loadGlyphs();
        } catch (SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public void toggleRender()
    {
        if(shouldRenderFont){
            shouldRenderFont = false;
        }else{
            shouldRenderFont = true;
        }
    }
    public void toggleRender(boolean doRender)
    {
        shouldRenderFont = doRender;
    }

    public void renderFont(float x, float y, String text, FloatBuffer orthographicProjectionMatrix, FloatBuffer perspectiveProjectionMatrix)
    {
        if(!shouldRenderFont) { return; }

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadMatrix(orthographicProjectionMatrix);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

            GL11.glPushMatrix();

                GL11.glLoadIdentity();
                GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

                font.drawString(x, y, text);

                GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

            GL11.glPopMatrix();

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadMatrix(perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
}
```

Thats how I call it :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bunchofpunch.game;

import bunchofpunch.fonts.FontVeranda;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Alex
 */
public class GameScreenHUD extends GameScreen
{
    float space = 20f;
    float width = 250f;
    float height = 200f;

    World world;

    public GameScreenHUD(World world){this.world = world;}

    @Override
    public void renderScreen() {

        //this is a instace of "FontVeranda.java"
        world.font.renderFont(Game.WIDTH-width+50, Game.WIDTH-height-space-160, "My Text is here", 
        World.orthographicProjectionMatrix, World.perspectiveProjectionMatrix);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadMatrix(World.orthographicProjectionMatrix);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

            glPushMatrix();

                glLoadIdentity();
                glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

                TextureManager.hud.bind();

                glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                    glVertex2f(Game.WIDTH-space-width, Game.HEIGHT-space);
                    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                    glVertex2f(Game.WIDTH-space, Game.HEIGHT-space);
                    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
                    glVertex2f(Game.WIDTH-space, Game.HEIGHT-height-space);
                    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                    glVertex2f(Game.WIDTH-space-width, Game.HEIGHT-height-space);

                glEnd();

                glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

            glPopMatrix();

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadMatrix(World.perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont quite understand how this should help me. I have no transparent area. And I belive the problem is something with the Slick fonts render method.

Comment: Just from what I see, I would say you arent properly setting a backing / background color just prior to calling the font drawing routine.  The font drawing routine is probably just taking the currently buffered background color and applying it.  Further I cant see what mode you're in whether you have alpha blending with 4 color channels or are working in 3 color channels etc...?  It could be that you are working in 24 bit color mode with alpha blending turned off.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the text is drawn with a texture for each letter applied to the quad. Any transparent objects must be drawn after objects that they appear in front of. Changing the draw order to draw the text last is the only good solution. Basically, you already found the solution. Draw the text second. Although there are some ways to get the effect you want while drawing the text first, I really don't recommend them.